# Using C#'s Marshal.PtrToStructure on a C++ struct containing two bitsets

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to use my existing code to map a C++ structure containing std::bitsets to a C# version of it.

My code works great on these simple objects:

```
// C++ struct
struct log_t 
{
    uint16 current;
    bool   complete[64];
};

C# struct
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Log
{
    public UInt16 current;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public byte[] complete;
}

// Convert the C# struct back to bytes for the C++ app to use
private byte[] GetObjectBytes(object obj)
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);
    byte[] arr = new byte[size];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(obj, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return arr;
}
```

How do I map the following C++ structs to C# structs that contains two std::bitsets? I wish to use them in the same manner as above.

```
struct items_table
{
    std::bitset<512> keyList;
    std::bitset<512> seenList;
};

struct items
{
    std::array<items_table, 7> tables;
};
```

SOLUTION

I used byte[] arrays in C# to represent the bitsets in C++.  I then had to access each bit like this:

```
    private void AddItem(int ItemId, KeyItems keyitems)
    {
        decimal byteIndex = (ItemId % 512) / 8;
        decimal bitInByteIndex = (ItemId % 512) % 8;
        keyitems.tables[ItemId / 512].keyList[(int)byteIndex] |= (byte)(1 << (byte)bitInByteIndex);
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you not attempt interop on C++ `std` classes at all, unless there is no other way (such as changing your C++ code). The memory layout of `std::bitset` is not guaranteed at all. Different versions of the compiler might produce incompatible layouts of the class.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I don't own the C++ code and have no control over it.

Answer (score 1):

We use interop a lot where I work, and though I haven't had to handle this situation, I suggest you treat your bitsets as byte arrays (`byte[]` in C#, I believe `char[]` in C++ unless you're aliasing `char`).  After all 512 bits is just 64 contiguous bytes.

I admit I haven't given you a full explanation of the syntax, my apologies, but I hope this gets you pointed in the right direction.

If your C# end needs to use them as `BitArray` instances, you could create properties on your struct there and just make them calculated, based on your `byte[]`s.  That does no harm for interop; the marshaller doesn't try to convert them across code boundaries in either direction.

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated the question and found a solution based on your suggestion to use byte arrays to represent the bitset.

Comment: I'm glad this helped.  Interop is always kind of a drag.